# Jquery get raw html of this node

Tags: jquery, html

The initial table full html is extracted from other website.

I need to do further processing for it.

When wording match, I want to fetch the html block of the whole table only, to overwrite the content inside the current `<body>` tag.

Problem now is fail to print out the html block of the whole table.

'Header Title' is dynamic value. From time to time I will add in more comparison criteria. if matching, then I will retrieve table html only, `starting from <table> to </table>` , all other htmls inside body tag but outside of the table tag need to wipe out.

```
    <body>
  <!-- Additional HTMl code -->
  <div align="right">
    <table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Header Title</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="32" valign="top">Date : <strong>01/01/2011 </strong> <br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        ...
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Additional HTMl code -->
  </div>
</body>
$("*").each(function() {
  if($(this).children().length==0){
    if($(this).text()=="Header Title"){
      alert('match');
      alert($(this).closest('table').html()); //not working...
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. Can you explain more what you need to do, and how what you're doing right now isn't working?

Comment: Basically 'Header Title' is dynamic value.
From time to time I will add in more comparison criteria.

if matching, then I will retrieve table html only (for other usage), all other htmls inside body no need.

Comment: so basically you are saying based on the header title, if it matches what you are looking for, then retrive all html content of all tables in the html excluding everything outside of tables right?

Comment: Yes. If header match, then I will retrieve the full html code of the table for which this header is reside in. All other html codes outside of the table can wipe out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:** tested, working: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/t9ysV/1/

**UPDATE:** wait, missing starting/ending `<table>` tags, work in progress...

Acually your javascript (tho missing `});` from the end) does just that:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().size() == 0) {
        if ($(this).text() == "Header Title") {
            alert('match');
            $("<div id='temp' />").appendTo("body");
            $(this).closest('table').appendTo("#temp");
            data = $("#temp").html();
            $("#temp").remove();
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

The trick is to put the table in a temporary element, and read the html content of that element. (Then remove it ofc.)

Comment: thank you very much for your div temp code, instead of seeing [object][object], now I finally able to see the actual output correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This will search the page for tables in a div and look for the first row's contents.  If it's a match, it will return the full table.  It will do this for however many tables in the page.

```
$(function(){
    var t = $("div table");
    $(t).each(function(){
        if($(this).find("tr:first-child").text().trim() == "Header Title Match") {
            console.debug($(this).parent("div").html());
        }
    })
})
```

Obviously, you'll need to remove the console stuff.